# In my SpringBoot application (with MVC), @Value or Enviroment is not reading value from config file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a SpringBoot applicaiton with MVC. In this I have a `AppConfig` class like below.
I have a config file `app.conf` in location "`/etc/config/`". The file has the following properties

```
logging.level.org.gtri=DEBUG
log.file=/var/log/myapp/app.log
log.file.rolling.naming.pattern=/var/log/myapp/app.%i.log
log.file.rolling.size=10MB
app.feature.enabled=True
```

The problem I am facing is that

1. With @Value annotation the value for the property is always "null"
2. Tried with Environment getProperty but it throws parsing exception

Log:

```
[2024-01-05 14:13:36,391] [INFO ] localhost-startStop-6 o.g.d.c.AppConfig.applicationFeatureStatus - [---DEV_TEST---] Application feature enable value from file = null
[2024-01-05 14:13:36,408] [ERROR] localhost-startStop-6 o.g.d.c.AppConfig.applicationFeatureStatus - Exception occurred while parsing applicationFeatureStatus.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

AppConfig Class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/config/app.conf", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/local-config-${spring.profiles.active}.conf", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Slf4j
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Autowired 
    PageRequestInterceptor pageRequestInterceptor;
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${app.feature.enabled:False}")
    private String appFeatureEnabled;

       
    @Bean
    public Boolean applicationFeatureStatus()
    {
        Boolean appFeatureStatus = false;

        try
        {
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Application feature enable value from file = {} , TIMEOUT = {}", appFeatureEnabled);            
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Applicaiton feature Flag (ENV) = {}", env.getProperty("app.feature.enabled"));
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Parsed Applicaiton feature status = {}", Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled));
            appFeatureStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.error("Exception occurred while parsing appFeatureEnabled.", ex);
        }

        return appFeatureStatus;
    }

    @Bean
    public LogInterceptor loggingAspects() { return new LogInterceptor(); }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        //....... Code for resources
        //......
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) { registry.addInterceptor(pageRequestInterceptor); }

}
```

## How I fixed:

I added a new config `MyConfig` class below and moved all the `applicationFeatureStatus` Bean and property soruces.
Now I the property value is read from the file and able to use @Value and Environment in both config classes.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Slf4j
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Autowired 
    PageRequestInterceptor pageRequestInterceptor;
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${app.feature.enabled:False}")
    private String appFeatureEnabled;

       
    @Bean
    public void testBeanForAppFeatureStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Application feature enable value from file = {} , TIMEOUT = {}", appFeatureEnabled);            
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Applicaiton feature Flag (ENV) = {}", env.getProperty("app.feature.enabled"));
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Parsed Applicaiton feature status = {}", Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled));
            appFeatureStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.error("Exception occurred while parsing appFeatureEnabled.", ex);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public LogInterceptor loggingAspects() { return new LogInterceptor(); }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        //....... Code for resources
        //......
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) { registry.addInterceptor(pageRequestInterceptor); }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/config/app.conf", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:/local-config-${spring.profiles.active}.conf", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
@Slf4j
public class MyConfig
{
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Value("${app.feature.enabled:False}")
    private String appFeatureEnabled;

       
    @Bean
    public Boolean applicationFeatureStatus()
    {
        Boolean appFeatureStatus = false;

        try
        {
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Application feature enable value from file = {} , TIMEOUT = {}", appFeatureEnabled);            
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Applicaiton feature Flag (ENV) = {}", env.getProperty("app.feature.enabled"));
            log.info("[---DEV_TEST---] Parsed Applicaiton feature status = {}", Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled));
            appFeatureStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(appFeatureEnabled);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.error("Exception occurred while parsing appFeatureEnabled.", ex);
        }

        return appFeatureStatus;
    }

}
```

**Even though I fixed it, I do not have a clue why the @Value or Environment is not working in the config class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer**

Comment: There is a typo in <em>@Value("${app.featrue.enabled:False}")</em>,  _featrue_

Comment: Oops, that typo was happend when I modifed the code to post here. I corrected it.
My actual code is having as `@Value("${app.featrue.enabled:False}")`

The problem I have is the @Value / Environment is returning null in the class AppConfig (which uses WebMvcConfigurer) where as the class MyConfig able to return the value from the config file. I even added bean `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in AppConfig but no use...